# R: Manipulating input dataframe in a loop/w. purrr-functions without creating a new object

Tags: r, function, loops, purrr

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best ways to optimize my work with functions and loops (occasionally using `purrr`).

This is a problem I've run into a few times, and I'm hoping that you might be able to give me a conceptual answer as to what's wrong. Yes, I've read R4DS on iteration (and the other chapters), but I'm still feeling shaky.

To illustrate, I recently ran into the problem when splitting some names into multiple columns.

```
df <- data.frame(fullname_clear = c("One Very Long Name", "Oneword", "Normal Guy"), 
                     Occupation = c("Painter", "Pastor", "Paralegal")
```

The task is then to split the name-column into 3 columns where the first word is put in a column called `first_name`, the last word is put in `last_name`, and everything else is put in `middle_name`. If a person only has 1 name, it should be listed as a last name. I've done this with the following snippet of code:

```
df$first_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
df$middle_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
df$last_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))


 for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (!grepl("\\s", df$fullname_clear[[i]])) {
    df$first_name[[i]] <- NA
    df$middle_name[[i]] <- NA
    df$last_name[[i]] <- df$fullname_clear[[i]]
  } else {
    df$first_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], 1)
    df$middle_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], 2, -2)
    df$last_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], -1)
  }
}

df$middle_name[df$middle_name==""] <- NA
```

I guess it could be done more neatly, but it works. I would love, however, to turn it into a function which would take just the name of the dataframe as input and then return the very same dataframe (same name and everything) with the three new name-columns.

I naïvely tried this:

```
name_splitter1 <- function(df){
  df <- df
  df$first_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  df$middle_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  df$last_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (!grepl("\\s", df[i, "fullname_clear"])) {
      df[i, "first_name"] <- NA
      df[i, "middle_name"] <- NA
      df[i, "last_name"] <- df1[i, "fullname_clear"]
    } else {
      df[i, "first_name"] <- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], 1)
      df[i, "middle_name"] <- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], 2, -2)
      df[i, "last_name"] <- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], -1)
    }
  }
  df$middle_name[df$middle_name==""] <- NA
}
name_splitter1(test_df)
```

and also

```
test_df <- name_splitter1(test_df)
```

Without any luck. I've also tried using `<<-` instead of `<-` without any success. I can, however, get it to work if I just alter the function into something like this:

```
name_splitter <- function(df){
  df1 <<- df
    df1$first_name <<- vector("character", nrow(df))
    df1$middle_name <<- vector("character", nrow(df))
    df1$last_name <<- vector("character", nrow(df))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (!grepl("\\s", df1[i, "fullname_clear"])) {
      df1[i, "first_name"] <<- NA
      df1[i, "middle_name"] <<- NA
      df1[i, "last_name"] <<- df1[i, "fullname_clear"]
    } else {
      df1[i, "first_name"] <<- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], 1)
      df1[i, "middle_name"] <<- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], 2, -2)
      df1[i, "last_name"] <<- word(df1[i, "fullname_clear"], -1)
    }
  }
    df1$middle_name[df1$middle_name==""] <<- NA
}
```

My question is: Can someone tell me conceptually a) What I'm not getting and b) How to get a function that'll just take a dataframe as input and then return an altered version of the same dataframe with the aforementioned changes?

Please do let me know if I need to improve on this question in any way!

Cheers,
Mathias

Comment: add `return(...)` statement at end of function?

Comment: Okay, that was simple. Not sure I get the proper use of `return()`, but you're absolutely right that it seems to work well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of this as a vector operation instead of a loop.

If you only want to use base r functions you could do:

```
df2 <- df
df2$first_name <- trimws(regmatches(df$fullname_clear,gregexpr("^\\S+\\s",df$fullname_clear)))
df2$middle_name <- trimws(regmatches(df$fullname_clear,gregexpr("\\s.+\\s",df$fullname_clear)))
df2$last_name <- trimws(regmatches(df$fullname_clear,gregexpr("\\s\\S+$",df$fullname_clear)))

df2$first_name <- ifelse(df2$first_name == "character(0)", NA_character_, df2$first_name)
df2$middle_name <- ifelse(df2$middle_name == "character(0)", NA_character_, df2$middle_name)
df2$last_name <- ifelse(df2$last_name == "character(0)", NA_character_, df2$last_name)
```

> ```
>       fullname_clear Occupation first_name middle_name last_name
> 1 One Very Long Name    Painter        One   Very Long      Name
> 2            Oneword     Pastor       <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
> 3         Normal Guy  Paralegal     Normal        <NA>       Guy
> ```

In this case I'm using regmatches to subset the string for each case. However, when I subset I am also including the space that leads/follows the string in question so I have to trimws.

This code creates a problem if there is nothing there. One function returns `character(0)` which then gets turned into "character(0)" as a string. So I have to find any "character(0)" and replace it with NA. There are easier ways to do this in dplyr and maybe in base-r, but I'm not well practiced in base-r.

---

Alternative the `stringr` package handles a lot of these errors automatically and is much easier to read:

```
library(stringr)
df3 <- df
df3$first_name <- str_trim(str_extract(df3$fullname_clear,"^\\S+\\s"))
df3$middle_name <- str_trim(str_extract(df3$fullname_clear,"\\s.+\\s"))
df3$last_name <- str_trim(str_extract(df3$fullname_clear,"\\s\\S+$"))
```

> ```
>       fullname_clear Occupation first_name middle_name last_name
> 1 One Very Long Name    Painter        One   Very Long      Name
> 2            Oneword     Pastor       <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
> 3         Normal Guy  Paralegal     Normal        <NA>       Guy
> ```

---

**Update:**

Your function is trying to directly address global variables. Why not just return an answer?

```
split_names <- function(in.df){
  in.df$first_name <- str_trim(str_extract(in.df$fullname_clear,"^\\S+\\s"))
  in.df$middle_name <- str_trim(str_extract(in.df$fullname_clear,"\\s.+\\s"))
  in.df$last_name <- str_trim(str_extract(in.df$fullname_clear,"\\s\\S+$"))

  return(in.df)
}

df1 <- split_names(df)
```

You can also use your own working code using variables that are limited to the scope of the function. Then return the results.

```
split_names_1 <- function(df) {
  df$first_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  df$middle_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  df$last_name <- vector("character", nrow(df))


  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (!grepl("\\s", df$fullname_clear[[i]])) {
      df$first_name[[i]] <- NA
      df$middle_name[[i]] <- NA
      df$last_name[[i]] <- df$fullname_clear[[i]]
    } else {
      df$first_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], 1)
      df$middle_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], 2, -2)
      df$last_name[[i]] <- word(df$fullname_clear[[i]], -1)
    }
  }

  df$middle_name[df$middle_name==""] <- NA

  return(df)
}

df2 <- split_names_1(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the problem is not to get the task done. The code provided in the question works fine. I was rather looking for a way to compile it all in a function.

Comment: Updates look fine. It seems to be the case that I simply missed out on `return(df)`. Any brief conceptual clarification as to why the argument is needed?

Comment: I'd have to check your errors to be sure, but you need to use return whenever the last object that you modify is not the object that you want to return. In your case, the last object you modify is `df1$middle_name[df1$middle_name==""]`. But you want to return the entire dataframe and not just a vector sub-set of it.